# PL/SQL Stored Procedure - IF THEN ELSE condition

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I wrote the stored procedure myself and I'm doing it this way for my own learning. This is for a data warehouse and what is happening is that between the two parameters the table will be populated with dates from day one of the START_YEAR to last day of the END_YEAR. My stored procedure will contain more columns, but I figure to start little by little and work on the errors as I build on the code. So for example  **sp_DATE_D(2000,2001)** and when you run a select statement in Application Express for one row it returns the following

**Expection when I run the SELECT statement for one row**
DATE_KEY = 01/01/2000
FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION = Saturday, January 1, 2000
DAY_OF_WEEK = 6 
LAST_DAY_OF_WEEK_INDICATOR = Y --Y if Saturday and N for everything else.

Table Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE DATE_D
(  
    DATE_KEY DATE NOT NULL,
    FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL,
    DAY_OF_WEEK NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL,
    LAST_DAY_OF_WEEK_INDICATOR CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT DATE_D_PK PRIMARY KEY (DATE_KEY)
);
```

Stored Procedure:
I understand that there is a condition that needs to be implemented, just not sure where. I tried the IF THEN ELSE, but no success.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_DATE_D(v_START_YEAR IN INT, v_END_YEAR IN INT) AS

v_CURRENT_DATE DATE;
v_END_DATE DATE;

BEGIN

v_CURRENT_DATE := TO_DATE('0101' || v_START_YEAR, 'MMDDYYYY');
v_END_DATE     := TO_DATE('1231' || v_END_YEAR, 'MMDDYYYY');

DELETE FROM DATE_D;

WHILE v_CURRENT_DATE <= v_END_DATE 
LOOP
INSERT INTO DATE_D
(
    DATE_KEY, 
    FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION,
    DAY_OF_WEEK
)   
VALUES
(
    v_CURRENT_DATE,
    TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'Day, Month DD, YYYY'),
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'D')) - 1
);
BEGIN
   IF TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'DAY') != 'Saturday' THEN
    INSERT INTO DATE_D (LAST_DAY_OF_WEEK_INDICATOR) values(LAST_DAY_OF_WEEK_INDICATOR = 'N');       
   ELSE     
    INSERT INTO DATE_D(LAST_DAY_OF_WEEK_INDICATOR) values(LAST_DAY_OF_WEEK_INDICATOR = 'Y');
   END IF;
END;


v_CURRENT_DATE := v_CURRENT_DATE + 1;

END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**ERROR**
Compilation failed,line 49 (17:03:53)
PL/SQL: ORA-00917: missing commaCompilation failed,line 49 (17:03:53)
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignoredCompilation failed,line 51 (17:03:53)
PL/SQL: ORA-00917: missing commaCompilation failed,line 51 (17:03:53)
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: It always helps to explain what you expect to happen and what actually happens, including any error messages you get.

Comment: @AlexPoole- I have edited the post with the expectation and error s well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to insert a second row in the table in your if/else, which I don't think is what you really want. I'm not sure why you've put the `LAST_DAY_OF_WEEK_INDICATOR =` part inside the values clause; perhaps you're trying to update but are (quite) confused about the syntax for that.

The if condition will never be matched though, you're converting the date to a day name with `DAY` which gives you the day name all in uppercase. It's also padded to the length of the longest day name in your date language, which is Wednesday in English, so you'd actually have to compare against `SATURDAY` (with a trailing space) unless you included [an `FM` format modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216); and you're assuming whoever calls this will have an English-language session, which is maybe allowable for this exercise.

Really you want to just do one insert rather than an insert followed by an update. (I'm ignoring the inefficiency of a row-by-row approach as you said this intentional for learning). So you can include the indicator column and its value as part of the existing insert. To do an if/else within an SQL statement you can use decode or a case expression:

```
...
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO DATE_D
    (
      DATE_KEY, 
      FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION,
      DAY_OF_WEEK,
      LAST_DAY_OF_WEEK_INDICATOR
    )   
    VALUES
    (
      v_CURRENT_DATE,
      TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'Day, Month DD, YYYY'),
      TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'D')) - 1,
      CASE 
        WHEN TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'FMDay') = 'Saturday' THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
      END
    );
    v_CURRENT_DATE := v_CURRENT_DATE + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

If you did want to allow for different session languages there's a third argument to `to_char()` which allows you to specify which language to use for day and month names.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bbabd/1).

Notice the padding in the `FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION` column, which causes the elements to be aligned. If you want that to look more natural, use the FM modifier for that column value too.

Comment: Thanks. Clear explanation as well.